# How to delete last char

Tags: delphi

How to delete last character of String with `substring` or anything ?

For example;

```
var
  query : String;
begin
  query:= 'test=1&line=5&'; 
end;
```

**Output must be :**

```
query -> test1&line=5
```

Comment: `SetLength(query,Length(query)-1);`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
var
  query : String;
begin
  query:= 'test=1&line=5&';
  delete(query,length(query),1);
```

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Actually, the DELETE and INSERT procedures (as well as COPY function) is always 1-based, if I'm not mistaken. The only part that is different is direct character indexing of a string expression, ie. s[1] will be the 1st character on desktop compilers, but the 2nd character on mobile compilers.

Comment: Just an update to the s[x] comment above: In current versions of Delphi, s[1] will be the first character in *all* editions of PASCAL compilers.

Answer (score 19):

A third option is this:

```
SetLength(Query,LENGTH(Query)-1)
```

Comment: +1 - this achieves the required effect directly and succinctly.  It does "exactly what it says on the tin" with minimum opportunity for misinterpretation or errors in implementation.

Answer (score 10):

I think I would write this as:

```
NewValue := OldValue.Substring(0, OldValue.Length - 1);
```

I think the functional interface, that is a function returning a new value, is usually to be preferred over a procedure with side-effects. I find the assignment operator is a clear indicator that a new value is being assigned to the variable. Using a functional approach makes the syntax much cleaner when you want the new value to be stored in a different variable from the original value.

Comment: I agree with David Heffernan.  His answer and reasoning show and explain a better way to delete characters from a string.

Comment: `Copy(str, 1, length(str)-1)`, for olders versions

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound Or `LeftStr`. But yes, I'm assuming XE3 or later.

Comment: In XE3+, you could alternatively use `TStringHelper.Remove()`, eg: `query.Remove(query.Length-1)`

Comment: SetLength() is not a procedure with **side effects**, it is a procedure with one, very direct effect.  The OP's requirement is to shorten an existing string, not create a shorter copy.  Fabricating an assignment to achieve this is both a misleading and an unnecessarily verbose distraction from the actual intent.  Furthermore, it needlessly involves a further unconstrained parameter with the potential for unintentional errors.  imho This approach is clearly more likely to lead to errors in implementation and/or subsequent interpretation/modification.

Comment: @Deltics What errors are likely to arise from assignment? Please demonstrate. As for `SetLength` it absolutely has side effects. It mutates its arguments.

Comment: @Deltics I guess you have a different definition of what a **side effect** is. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/what-is-a-side-effect

Comment: +1. Substring is available in other (modern, Object Oriented) languages as well, making this method more familiar for developers new to Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

I actually was going to use this to another answer called "Delete last 5 characters from a string", probably not the best way to do this but it works for simple strings as #0 indicates a termination of a string.

for your example

```
Query[Length(Query)]:= #0;
```

For the other topic example I can'nt reply on

```
str[Succ(Length(str)) - 5]:= #0;
showmessage(str);
```

P.s
I would vote HeartWare answer as that would be the more acceptable way to do this. I was just showing for simple strings a quick alternative that has the desired effects(mainly for the other topic conceringing deleting the last 5 chars)

Answer (score 0):

```pascal
var
test: System.String;
begin
  test := 'Sample Text To Delete Last Character;!';
  test := Copy(test,1,length(test)-1);
  ShowMessage(test);
end;
```

Variable is Established;
A SampleText is provided to the Variable;
Variable then Reference itself in the Copy command which
the Copy command takes the variable string by coping it by its length from index 1(length)-1
which return the result to the variable itself;
A Message is used to show the result;

the result would be the text without exclamation; // Sample Text To Delete Last Character;

Comment: Since the question specifically wanted to know how to accomplish this, you should include some comments to explain what the code does and why you think it best addresses the question.